# Old values are not freed/garbage collected when you re-evaluate an assignment

Tags: evaluation, memory

For this code:

```
(* Cell 1 *)
generate := Module[{x}, x = Range[100 * 1000 * 1000]; x];

(* Cell 2 *)
g = generate[];
MemoryInUse[]
```

If I evaluate cell 2 repeatedly, the memory consumption keeps growing by 400 MB each time (as seen in the OS task manager). For some reason, it seems that Mathematica does not free the memory taken by the old value of `g`.

Can someone please explain what is going on here? And is there a way to force the freeing of old `g` values? Due to this issue I need to keep on quitting the Mathematica kernel.

Comment: Sometimes just calling `Share[]` already frees substantial memory.

Comment: @celtschk `Share[]` works by making sure that the same expression is not stored twice.  It uses pointers for duplicate occurrences, such as in `x^2` in `f[x^2, x^2]`.  Unfortunately it won't help with packed arrays like the one in the OP's example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to set

```
$HistoryLength = 0
```

(or other small value) at the beginning of the session to prevent `Out` from remembering previous outputs.  One non-obvious thing about `Out` is that if we do

```
In[1]:= a=1;
```

then `Out[1]` will still be set to `1` despite the semicolon at the end of the input!

There's also the `` CleanSlate` `` package which has a `ClearInOut` function that clears old inputs and outputs.

Comment: If you define `ignore[_]:=Null` you can selectively avoid this storage by writing `ignore[a=1]` instead of `a=1;`. Note that `(a=1;Null)` seems *not* to be sufficient.

Comment: @celtschk Yep, though seems like a lot of work.  Interesting observation about adding `Null`.

Comment: @celtschk I sometimes would do `a=1 //Null&` which is the same as you do. Probably the `Null` doesn't work because the actual full form of `a;` is `CompoundExpression[a, Null]`, equivalent to appending Null

Comment: That comment leads me to the following solution to get the expected behaviour: `Unprotect[CompoundExpression];CompoundExpression[x___]:=Last[Evaluate/@{x}];Protect[CompoundExpression]`

Comment: @Rojo: I just notice that your code assigns `Null` to `a`. I guess you meant `(a=1)//Null&` (but then, `Null&[a=1]` is shorter and indeed a nice alternative to my `ignore` function)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this satisfies your request.

```
$Pre = Function[input, If[input === Null, "Null"; Null, input]];
```

Basically, `$Pre` as a function acts on input expression. If the evaluation result of input is `Null`, then run `"Null";Null`, so only string "Null" will aggregate in memory for expression ended with `;`.

In this way, normal `Out[]` history(those expression without `;`) will retained, while `;` terminated expression output will not take up memory. I think this would be better than simply setting `$HistoryLength = 0`.