# Swap elements in list without copy

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a lists with 100,000 elements and would like two swap to entries without dublicating the list

Example:

```
a = {11,2,7,31};
swap[2,4]; (* how to implement this? *) 
a (* should print {11,31,7,2} *)
```

I can do

```
swap[i_,j_]:=(a=ReplacePart[a,{i->a[[j]],j->a[[i]]}])
```

but this copies the list and if there are many swaps this takes way too much time...

**Edit:** The important point of my question is how to do it without having Mathematica creating a copy of the list. This is in no way answered by the alleged duplicate.

Comment: You can use `swap = Function[{list,i,j},list[[{j,i}}]] = list[[i,j]],HoldFirst]`. Example: `lst = Range[10];
swap[lst, 3, 7];lst`

Comment: @LeonidShifrin. What you have posted has syntax errors. You probably meant to write `swap = Function[{list, i, j}, list[[{j, i}]] = list[[{i, j}]], HoldFirst]`

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks for spotting this. Actually, I first posted the comment, then tested and found those error, but got distracted and forgot to paste the correct version.

Comment: if you just want to do numbers, you can use the bitwise XOR swap trick ... a^=b;b^=a;a^=b; http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BitXor.html

Comment: Dear duplicate markers, I do not see where this question has been answered before. The linked question and its answers do in no way tackle the issues of not creating a copy of the list.

Comment: @Danvil Agreed. voted to reopen.

Comment: The form `a[[{2,4}]] = a[[{4,2}]]` does in-place modification.  This is covered in the marked duplicate.  Are you asserting that this does not perform as claimed or desired?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Could you try this: `ClearAll[a, miu, miu2, miu3];
miu = MemoryInUse[];
a = RandomReal[10, {10^6}];
miu2 = MemoryInUse[];
a[[{2, 4}]] = a[[{4, 2}]];
miu3 = MemoryInUse[];
miu2 - miu // Print;
miu3 - miu2 // Print;`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Hmmm, if I copy this back, my results differ; strange...

Comment: @Sjoerd Sorry, I missed your comment.  I get `8000336` and `136` for output.  What do you get?  Also consider `MaxMemoryUsed[]` perhaps.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Have you seen my email?

Comment: @Sjoerd No, but I just checked now and I see it.

Comment: @Sjoerd Initial thought: you forgot about `$HistoryLength`.  Try: `$HistoryLength = 0;` first.

Comment: @Sjoerd Please read this explanation: [(30634)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30634)

Comment: Can someone please reopen the question. This is definitely not a duplicate.

Answer (score 12):

**Edit 2:** Thanks to @Rojo for pointing out something I forgot about, which leads me to revise my answer as well as to the following conclusion:

***Mathematica* can swap elements in an array without copying the array.**

What I neglected was `$HistoryLength`.  Mine is set at `$HistoryLength = 5`; the standard  default is `Infinity`.  The issue it causes is that the result of `a = Range[100000000];` is stored.  When the swap is computed, the value `a` has to be copied so that the value in the history remains unchanged (compare with the example from the original answer, `b = a; b[[1]] = -1;` down below).  If you set `$HistoryLength = 0` then the swap occurs in place without copying `a`.  See, for instance, [Old values are not freed/garbage collected when you re-evaluate an assignment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3376/old-values-are-not-freed-garbage-collected-when-you-re-evaluate-an-assignment).  Blank lines indicate separate input cells.

```
Quit[]

$HistoryLength = 0;

a = Range[100000000];

MaxMemoryUsed[]
(* 823174480 *)

a[[{4, 2}]] = a[[{2, 4}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.000011, Null} *)

MaxMemoryUsed[]
(* 823175512 *)
```

Compare with the evidence I gave in my original answer, during which `$HistoryLength` was `5`:

```
Quit[]

$HistoryLength = 5;         (* added *)

a = Range[10^8];

MaxMemoryUsed[]
(* 823176384 *)

a[[{4, 2}]] = a[[{2, 4}]];  (* If $HistoryLength >= 2, then the result of Range[10^8],
                               two commands ago, has to be preserved in the history *)

MaxMemoryUsed[]             (* So the memory usage doubles *)
(* 1623180112 *)
```

In the other part of my original answer, the problem was to explain why the timing seemed fast on iterated swaps inside a `Do` loop.  The explanation is the same as above.  The intermediate results of each iteration are not stored in the history, so no copying is done.  If `$HistoryLength = 0`, then all swaps will be fast.

```
Quit[] 

$HistoryLength = 0

SeedRandom[1];
a = Range[10^8];
With[{indices = Range[10^8]},
  sw = Table[RandomSample[indices, 2], {1000}]
  ];

Do[a[[s]] = a[[Reverse@s]], {s, sw}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.002138, Null} *)
```

If `HistoryLength` is changed to `5` or so, a copy of the initial value of `a` will be made on the first swap, but subsequent swaps will be fast.  This may be inferred by comparing the `Do` with one that does one swap:

```
Do[a[[s]] = a[[Reverse@s]], {s, sw}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.430604, Null} *)
```

For further confirmation, we can see that the bulk of the time corresponds to how long it takes to write `10^8` integers to RAM:

```
a = Range[10^8]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.371801, Null} *)
```

A similar comparison to an operation that requires reading and writing:  Evaluating `b = a` creates a reference but does not copy memory; the subsequent command `b[[1]] = -1` forces *Mathematica* to copy the list (as well as change `b[[1]]`).

```
b = a;
b[[1]] = -1; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.437203, Null} *)
```

---

*Side issue*:
The code for the iterated swaps in the original answer was somewhat different.  It used `a` instead of `With` for the indices to generate the list of swaps `sw`.  Using `a` this way causes `a` to get copied on the first swap even if `$HistoryLength = 0`.

```
Quit[] 

$HistoryLength = 0

SeedRandom[1];
a = Range[10^8];
sw = Table[RandomSample[a, 2], {1000}];

Do[a[[s]] = a[[Reverse@s]], {s, sw}]; // AbsoluteTiming  (* first time *)
(* {0.405094, Null} *)

Do[a[[s]] = a[[Reverse@s]], {s, sw}]; // AbsoluteTiming  (* second time *)
(* {0.002062, Null} *)
```

I do not fully understand this.  A possible hypothesis is that a reference to the original value of `a` is maintained via the `RandomSample` code; however, it is not a thoroughly satisfying hypothesis.

---

**Edit 1**: Illustration of the multiple swap code.

```
SeedRandom[1];
a = Range[20]
sw = Table[RandomSample[a, 2], {5}]
(*
  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}
  {{6, 1}, {8, 1}, {3, 4}, {1, 17}, {15, 4}}
*)

Do[a[[s]] = a[[Reverse@s]], {s, sw}];
a
(*
  {17, 2, 4, 15, 5, 1, 7, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 3, 16, 8, 18, 19, 20}
*)
```

Comment: So this means Mathematica code runs faster if `$HistoryLength=0`? That's good to know!

Answer (score 5):

```
ClearAll@swap
SetAttributes[swap, HoldFirst];

swap[list_, a_, b_] :=
 With[{temp = list[[a]]},
  list[[a]] = list[[b]];
  list[[b]] = temp]

a = {11, 2, 7, 31};

swap[a, 2, 4]; a
```

> {11, 31, 7, 2}

```
b = Range[100000];

Do[swap[b, 2, 4], {1000}] // Timing
```

> {0.015600, Null}

Comment: Thank you! That `HoldFirst` was a very important hint.

Comment: You could even get rid of the `temp` write: `swap[list_, a_, b_] := {list[[a]], list[[b]]} = {list[[b]], list[[a]]}`

Comment: @nikie thanks I just learnt this from m_goldberg's answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking if you can do the swap in-place, that is, by destructively modifying the list containing the elements you want to swap, I believe what you ask is impossible. As far as can I tell, *Mathematica* never modifies a list in place, although it sometimes creates the illusion that it does.

Consider

```
a = {11, 2, 7, 31}; b = a; a === b
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
a[[{4, 2}]] = a[[{2, 4}]]; {a, b}
```

> ```
> {{11, 31, 7, 2}, {11, 2, 7, 31}}
> ```

If the swap had really been made in-place, both `a` and `b` would have been modified. But since `b` remains unmodified, `a` must have been rebound to a newly created list containing the result of the swap. Therefore, there are now two lists in memory where there had only been one before.

Comment: But would it also copy the list if no other symbol referenced it? Otherwise, how do you explain @eldo's timing results?

Comment: @nikie. Yes, it would. As for edo's timing, what's to explain? His timing only tells us _Mathematica_ can copy lists very fast.

Comment: Did you try playing with the numbers? I find it hard to believe that Mathematica can copy a 8 GB list 100.000 times in less than 2 seconds. With a GHz CPU, it should take about a second (order of magnitude) to copy it *once*.

Comment: So there is no way to do a simple swap without copying a huge list of data?

Comment: @Danvil. Not that I know of. I once spent two days trying to find a way make _Mathematica_ modify a list in-place, but failed.

Comment: @nikie I tried to explain this in my answer (up to a point).  See if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tmp variable x, if you want to swap a & b, first let x = a, then a = b, then b = tmp.

Comment: `{a, b} = {b, a}` preforms a swap in _Mathematica_, no temporary variable required.